# The update info is outdated, white triangle with exclamation sign in system tray

Tags: update-manager, updates

I've got the triangle with exclamation sign inside in system tray, description is the following :

> The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network
> problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update
> manually by clicking on this icon and then selecting 'Check for
> updates' and check if some of the listed repositories fail.

[image: triangle in systray]

[image: update manager window]

'Check' updates doesn't help - it shows no updates everytime.
It would be greatful if somebody could help me to solve it

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`  -  Also add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: sorry for stupid question :) Mentioned outputs are quite long, what is the better way how to add it into a question ? Just copy/paste or somehow else ?

Comment: Yes - just copy and paste into the question.  Highlight the block of text and click the < $ > so that the text appears in a scrolling list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second**
You can re-install wine as it looks like it is the issue.
Run this at terminal: (note that this can remove your wine configuration, if you don't like this, change purge for remove):

```
sudo apt-get purge wine && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install && sudo apt-get install wine
```

**First**
I had the same issue once. Check your sources: open a terminal and paste `gksu software-properties-gtk`. If you are using a server from Brasil, try another server, maybe from USA.

If you have some ppa, try to disable them at "Others Softwares" tab.

Comment: choosing another server and disabling of ppa doesn't help

Comment: the update Managed is scheduled for daily checking

Comment: Have you checked the check box of wine showed in the picture and updated
?

Comment: No, I can't do that, it's not available

Comment: A had removed(uninstalled) Wine at all and so far it has solved an issue. Now the Update Manager is "up to date". Actually I didn't used Wine before - I had installed it just for experiment. So, I wasn't too sad after removing :) Thanks, your suggestion was helpful

Comment: I'm glad it worked ;-)